# IncreaseUserVA current value

Tags: windows, memory, bcdedit

I would like to look up my current value of "IncreaseUserVA".

There is this windows setting "BCDEDIT /set IncreaseUserVa 3000" which allows me to change a memory splitting.
Well, before I want to override this setting, where can it be found or where is it stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run BCDEdit from a command prompt to display the current boot config. This also includes the **IncreaseUserVa** setting.

Comment: Well it is not included. Not yet. I guess I have to set it first, so this is the point. What is it NOW? Before I set it.

Comment: if you haven't set anything, it doesn't show and the default value of 2GB applies.

Comment: How could you know it is  2GB? Where to find this value. I mean, yes everybody says it is 2GB. But just because someone said it before. I want to find out where it is set, where it can be found before I set it.

Comment: how I know this? because this is the how the Windows Memory Management for 32Bit applications works. read the Windows Internals Book 6 (part 2- Ch 10 page 229), it explains the x86 Address space layout.